# The mapping works, but a key can be ignored (unwantedly)

Tags: key-bindings

I've added this to my `.vimrc`: `nnoremap <C-S-w> :tabclose<CR>`, and it works!

But my problem is that <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> closes the terminal tab as well, ignoring the shift key specified in the above rule. So it will conflict with the window commands, such as
<kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> (instead of splitting the window, as soon as I hit <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> it tries to close a tab).

Also, the `:verbose map <c-w>` says there are no other conflicting mappings.

Although it must be irrelevant to the terminal (because `<c-w>` is showing a behavior internal to vim(closing a vim tab), I've also de-configured all the `ctrl+w`s from my terminal's configuration, but it's still not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:help CTRL-{char}`, under [notation section](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#notation),

```
CTRL-{char}     {char} typed as a control character; that is, typing {char}
                while holding the CTRL key down.  The case of {char} does not
                matter; thus CTRL-A and CTRL-a are equivalent.  But on some
                terminals, using the SHIFT key will produce another code,
                don't use it then.
```

If your terminal can produce another keycode when shift is also pressed, you can try to [tweak it to send another escape sequence for the shift combination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179779). I could not do it in Xterm.